# Why is OnStart running twice in this Android code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onstart

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(bundle != null){

            if(!bundle.containsKey(Constants.EXTRA_RECIPE_KEY) && !bundle.containsKey(Constants.EXTRA_RECIPE_CREATOR_ID)){

                Log.i(TAG, "onStart: bundle does not contain the recipe key and recipe creator id.");

            }else{
                String RECIPE_CREATOR_ID = bundle.getString(Constants.EXTRA_RECIPE_CREATOR_ID);
                String RECIPE_KEY = bundle.getString(Constants.EXTRA_RECIPE_KEY);
                mRecipeKey = RECIPE_KEY;
                mRecipeCreatorId = RECIPE_CREATOR_ID;
                Log.i(TAG, "RecieveRecipeCreatorId: Creator Key = " + mRecipeCreatorId);
                Log.i(TAG, "RecieveRecipeKey: Recipe Key = " + mRecipeKey);
                SetDetailsForIncomingRecipe();
            }

        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "onStart: bundle is null");
        }


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Without understanding how you're making use of the fragment in your app, and how you're interacting with the app, it's not really possible to say.

Comment: The fragment is the add/edit recipe fragment on a bottom nav view inside the main activity. I tried to past all the code for this fragment, but was unable to.

Comment: Let me know what code you'd like to see so I can paste it in